# How to solve RDLC Report Viewer design issue in IE 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have one design issue in RDLC Report Viewer in IE 10 Non Compatibility View. This site is host on two different server one is live for client and another one is developers for testing purpose, Client faced this issue in his live site but i can't face on development server and checked on live site then i faced this issue.

Any body have any idea about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't have IE10? People lie...

Comment: But he used IE 10 and he send us two screen shots for this problem.

Comment: OK, I tend to believe you then :-)